# Was Tarzan's dialogue in movies influenced by the Hulk Speak trope?

Tags: trope, adaptation-comparison, tarzan

Today I learnt that [Me Tarzan, You Jane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarzan_in_film_and_other_non-print_media#The_Weissm.C3.BCller_era) is a [Me Beam Up, You Scotty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_me_up,_Scotty).

[TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Franchise/Tarzan?from=Main.Tarzan) notes that movies from the franchise did have some Hulk Speak. Going through the TV Tropes page for the [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HulkSpeak), I couldn't find any earlier examples of the trope.

Did the Hulk Speak trope exist when the Tarzan movies were made, and did it influence dialogues in the movies compared to the original books?

Answer (score 8):

[Johnny Weissmuller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Weissmuller) was playing Tarzan, complete with Hulk-speak, as early as 1932;  the Hulk made his [first appearance in 1962](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(comics)).  If one had an influence on the other, it was Tarzan who created the trope, not the other way around.

Comment: The work a trope is named after isn't necessarily the [first instance of a trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TropeMakers?from=Main.TropeMaker). So "Hulk Speak" doesn't mean that the trope didn't exist before The Incredible Hulk did.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - That's not the point.  The point is simply that Tarzan was talking like that 30 years before the Hulk was.  Call it whatever you want, but Tarzan came first.